# Export-Csv doesn't work as I expected

Tags: powershell, csv

I have written a little script which should be export the output as CSV.
Here is my script:

```
$Jobs = Get-VBRJob

foreach ($Job in $Jobs) {
    $JobName = $Job.Name
    $Objects = $Job.GetObjectsInJob()
    $RestorePoints = Get-VBRRestorePoint -Backup $JobName
    $Day = $Job.ScheduleOptions.OptionsDaily.DaysSrv

    $RP = $RestorePoints.Count
    $VM = $Objects.Name

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "JobName" -Value $JobName
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Objects" -Value $Objects
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RestorePoints" -Value $RestorePoints
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Day" -Value $Day
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM" -Value $VM
}
$obj | Export-Csv $path -NoType
```

I read something about doing it via `New-Object PSObject`, so I tried this, but the CSV has only one line and returns the types of the attributes not the value. Only "JobName" and "VM" is working fine.

Can anyone help me to get the value of "Objects", "RestorePoints" and "Day" into CSV?

Comment: What are "Objects", "RestorePoints" and "Day" returning if you display their value on the shell? Also what das `$Objects.GetType()` .. return?

Comment: Value of Object in my CSV is `Veeam.Backup.Core.CObjectInJob[]`. Value of "Day" is `System.DayOfWeek[]`
and "RestorePoints" is `Veeam.Backup.Core.COib`. `$objects.GetType()` returns as "BaseType" `System.Array`, `$RestorePoints.GetType()`returns as "BaseType" `System.Object`, `$Day.GetType()` returns `System.Array` too

Comment: You'll need to decide how to handle multi-value attributes as you convert the objects into CSV. Perhaps you'll need to iterate through the System.DayOfWeek array and build a single string that makes sense, like "Monday | Tuesday | Thursday", then push that string to your CSV file. If you really need to maintain the arrays as you push this data to file, you might want to consider using XML or JSON to export the objects instead.

Comment: i need as result a csv file. I wanted to get an output where every of those properties is in one cell to the matching vm

Answer (score 1):

`$obj` contains only the object you just created, so after the loop completes, the variable holds the last object created in the loop, which is then exported to the CSV. A better approach would be outputting the created objects in the loop and collecting the loop output in a variable. I'd also recommend avoiding `Add-Member` unless you need to add members to an object that had been created elsewhere.

```
$obj = foreach ($Job in $Jobs) {
    ...
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'JobName'       = $JobName
        'Objects'       = $Objects
        'RestorePoints' = $RestorePoints
        'Day'           = $Day
        'VM'            = $VM
    }
}
```

Also, if the values you're assigning to the new object's properties are objects themselves, PowerShell will export the string representation of those objects to the CSV, which usually is the full name of the object's class. If you want particular values in the output you probably need to expand those further (e.g. `'VM' = $VM.Name`). What exactly you need to do there depends on the actual object, though, so I can't help much there without knowing more about the structure of the objects.